# First option automatically selected when select box with JQuery Multiselect UI by Eric Hynds is updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, server-sent-events

Im using the JQuery UI multiselect plugin by http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ to dynamically append elements to a select box

```
//Make filter cars multiselect
$("#cars_filter").multiselect({noneSelectedText:'Select cars'});

function populateCarfilter(){
    var opts="<option value=''>Select cars</option>";
    $.each(markers, function(idx, mar){
      if(mar.getVisible() && mar.get("car"))
     opts+="<option value='" + mar.get("id") + "'>" + mar.get("driver") + " - " + mar.get("car") + "</option>";
    });

    if($("#cars_filter").html()!=opts){
      var id = $("#cars_filter").val()
      $("#cars_filter").html(opts);
      $("#cars_filter").val(id);
      $("#cars_filter").multiselect('refresh');
    }    
}

populateCarfilter(); //This gets called every 2 secs automatically by SSE (server sent events)
```

Now, im facing a strange problem. The first option in the select box gets selected automatically everytime the select box is updated. Any way to fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: Browsers will automatically select the first option unless you add the multiple attribute to the element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Browsers will automatically select the first option unless you add the multiple attribute to the element.

See in you jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget javascript source file, They have implemented following

```
// browsers automatically select the first option
// by default with single selects
if( isSelected && !o.multiple ){
    labelClasses.push( 'ui-state-active' );
   }
```

Comment: Thank You,following what you said i added multiple="multiple" to the select element and that fixed the problem :)

Comment: I also noticed that if you have the select set to "required", one option is also selected, even if it is set to "multiple", which makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

and you can always ensure that it works by looping through the elements and setting the value to not selected as well like:

```
  click: function(event, ui){

 if(!ui.checked) 
 {   $.each( $('#select2 option'),function(i2, element2)
       {
                if( $(element2).val() === ui.value )
                {
                   if( $(element2).is(':selected') ) { 
             $(element2).attr('selected',false); 
                }
                     $(element2).remove().appendTo('#select1');
                    }        
        });
 }
```

}

This is just in the event that you are updating dynamically and want to ensure that is so... in my case I was updating / passing over elements from one dropdown to another and both had the multiple='multiple' attribute so I needed to ensure that when clicking in one was being removed, then appending it to the underlying select but still the first option was always selected.. hope it helps someone down the road.. it's a nice plugin